# How to nest states of lazy-loaded feature modules with @ngrx/store and @ngrx/entity?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I've been struggling for 2 days to compose states of a featureA ("scenarios") module and a nested featureB ("intents") module.

Here is the desired structure of my state (structure 1):

```
{
  authentication: { ... },
  router: { ... },
  scenarios: {
    resources: { ids: { ... }, entities: { ... } },
    intents: {
      resources: { ids: { ... }, entities: { ... } }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd be happy also with (structure 2):

```
{
  authentication: { ... },
  router: { ... },
  scenarios: { ids: { ... }, entities: { ... } },
  intents: { ids: { ... }, entities: { ... } },
}
```

Although it doesn't reflect the structure of my modules.

The problem with structure 1 is that `scenarios/reducers/index.ts` exposes a `ActionReducerMap`, `scenarios/modules/intents/reducers/index.ts` also exposes a `ActionReducerMap` and I don't know how to compose them. Everything I tried doesn't even compile because of type conflicts.

The problem with structure 2 is that the `intents` part of the state keeps being dropped out of the state because of the `IntentsModule` not being loaded at first page load and other reducers of the app doing their job.

Here is the code:

**/scenarios/scenarios.module.ts**:

```
import { reducers, getInitialState } from './reducers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,

    ScenariosRoutingModule,

    StoreModule.forFeature('scenarios', reducers, { initialState: getInitialState }),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ScenariosEffects]),
  ],
})
export class ScenariosModule {}
```

**/scenarios/reducers/index.ts**:

```
import * as fromRoot from '../../../app.reducers';
import * as fromScenarios from './scenarios.reducers';
import * as fromIntents from '../modules/intents/reducers';

export interface ScenariosState {
  resources: fromScenarios.State;
  intents: fromIntents.IntentsState;
}

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  scenarios: ScenariosState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ScenariosState> = {
  resources: fromScenarios.reducer,
  intents: fromIntents.reducers, <-- This is the part with types conflicts
};
```

**/scenarios/modules/intents/intents.module**:

```
import { reducers, getInitialState } from './reducers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,

    IntentsRoutingModule,

    StoreModule.forFeature('intents', reducers, { initialState: getInitialState }), <-- Also this part seems to add 'intents' as a top-level property of state
    EffectsModule.forFeature([IntentsEffects]),
  ],
})
export class IntentsModule {}
```

**/scenarios/modules/intents/reducers/index.ts**:

```
import * as fromIntents from './intents.reducers';

export interface IntentsState {
  resources: fromIntents.State;
}

export interface State {
  intents: IntentsState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<IntentsState> = {
  resources: fromIntents.reducer,
};

export function getInitialState(): IntentsState {
  return {
    resources: fromIntents.initialState,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `import` and `export` the `structure 2` `IntentsModule` in the root `AppModule`.
- `import` the `ScenariosModule` after the `IntentsModule` in the root `AppModule`.

**Do not** nest various `IntentsModules` under the `ScenariosModules`. Instead create separation and flatten your project structure as much as possible this is inherently required by `structure 2`.

I've found that a good approach for most situations with the exception of Auth related features is to create two modules per feature to be lazily loaded together yet decoupling state-management from the user-interface yet these corresponding modules should share an `API` of the same shape i.e:

- (`FrameworkLayoutModule` and `FrameworkStoreModule`) and (`AuthModule`).

Subsequently, reusable features may be lazily loaded by a `SecureModule` or a `PublicModule` as needed.

Comment: My ScenariosModule is loaded in the AppRoutingModule with `loadChildren: './modules/scenarios/scenarios.module#ScenariosModule'`. My IntentsModule is loaded by the ScenariosRoutingModule with `loadChildren: './modules/intents/intents.module#IntentsModule'`.
Can you point me to some good resources suggesting your approach with 2 modules per feature ? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This problem with use 'intents' store in two modules. And NgRx can`t create 'intents' store twice.

**solution 1**

remove 'intents' from scenarios.module or from intents.module if it dont use there.

**solution 2**

move 'intents' store into StoreModule.forRoot or into scenarios and intents parent module.